# Adding legend to geom_plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have managed to do this plot:

```
p3 <- ggplot() + 
geom_point(data = dv,aes(x = year,y = X1st.Qu.,group = 1),color = "yellow",shape = 95,size = 8) + 
geom_point(data = dv,aes(x = year,y = Mean,group = 1),color = "blue", shape = 21,size = 2) + 
geom_point(data = dv,aes(x = year,y = X3rd.Qu.,group = 1),color = "red",shape = 95,size = 8) +
geom_line(data = dv,aes(x = year,y = Mean,group = 1),color = "blue", shape = 21,size = .5)+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,size = 7))+
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
ggtitle("Statistical description per year") + 
labs(y="Statistics", x = "Year")
```

and would like to add a legend for the colours...how is it possible? I tried with scale_color_manual but didn't show up

As per last recommendation to move the color in the aes() arguments this is the result.

The colours are no longer mapped with color although the legend is shown (incorrectly)

[image]

Comment: @ user9737581 .. Can u add an image of what have you got, so that we can help you on what you want and what is missing?

Comment: just included it now

Comment: @ user9737581  Try `scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 1,1), breaks = c("lower Quartile", "mean",Upper Quartile"))`

Comment: Although  no complaints from R it does not show the legend still.

Comment: @ user9737581 :Just watched ur code closely, move the `color` argument inside the `aes`  for all the `geometry`  as this : `geom_point(data = dv,aes(x = year,y = X1st.Qu.,color = "yellow"),shape = 95,size = 8)`

Comment: Hi I edited my initial post to be able to see the result of the suggestion

Comment: The best long-term solution is to reshape your data (see linked question, some excellent answers there). Alternatively, use manual coloring: use `aes(...., color = 'my_label1')` for each colored geom. Then add `+ scale_color_manual(values = c('my_label1' = 'yellow', etc...))`. Then do the same for the shapes. It's a lot of work, which is why reshaping is easier!

Comment: @ user9737581: As pointed already by me and @Axeman kindly use `scale_shape_manual` for correcting the right colors in the legend...

Comment: @ user9737581 This solves ur problem.. add this line to have control on colors in legend.. scale_color_manual(values = c('yellow' = 'yellow', "blue" = 'blue','red' = 'red','blue' = 'blue'))